# HTML & Javascript to native app

Tags: javascript, html, native

I have build a training web app in html and javascrip with questions and answers.
I would like this app professionally for IOS and Android to be reconstructed.

My Question:
It is then possible to change the questions and answers?

Comment: If you have an API for Comments and Questions then yes, you can also make functions in Swift and Java to add Comments and Questions to your Database Setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I wonder if I can change the files I get back for example with new questions and answers.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "the files" that you "get back". Can you maybe give an example of how adding a comment on your site works?

Comment: Thank you for helping me

I give my html data to a programmer so he can see how the app works. Then he developed the app for IOS.
Then he gives me the files he created.

Question: Can I change the files for example a different background color or add new questions before I submit the app in the appstore.

Comment: I don't really get the purpose of your app then. You wrote, that you already built the web app. I it live?

Comment: Yes I have created it but only in html and javascript.
This is only for the programmer to see the function.
I would like to develop it professionally for ios, but then still change things.

Comment: Does your project allow users to ask questions and to give answers? If yes, then why would you not be able to ask a question after someone made what you have into an app?

Comment: Users can not ask questions.
It is a learning app in which the questions and answers are already stored.
Users can read the question and then display the answer. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is make sure that you use a database for your Questions and Answers.

Tell your Programmer to make sure that the Questions and Answers aren't hardcoded, but rather taken dynamically from a Database. For the easiest approach, go with MySQL.

Ask your Programmer to help you design a system that works for your case, for example, your Questions all have one Answer, so make a Table that has 3 Columns: an ID, a Question and an Answer.

Let your Programmer figure out a way to dynamically load the Data from your DB so that you can simply add any Q&A and the users will get them when their App queries your DB.